# Is there a way to test Instagram locations API as a sandbox user?

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api

I'm working on an application that requires the use of the locations API in Instagram.

As I'm currently in development I'm in the sandbox mode provided by Instagram. It's my understanding that while in sandbox mode I'll only be able to pull info from users that have agreed to be users of my application.

The problem, is it appears locations are not a single user account, but build by multiple people posting at a single location, or tagging the location to their posts: https://www.instagram.com/explore/locations/1486078/

Since there is no account to invite to my sandbox, is there no way to test the location API? I tried to look for a test account or some way around this, but was unable to find anything. It would seem a bit odd to have an API endpoint only available to approved applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Post a photo and tag a location using Instagram app.

Then use API to get photos from that location, the response will just have your photo in sandbox mode, once u go live, it will have all photos.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. It was pretty easy to create a new location, so I was able to post to this and pull my posts.

Comment: Peter, all my photos posted to the sandbox have no latitudes or longitudes. Is that just me?

Just want to click on a photo, and get the lats/lngs like the old API, is that still possible?